# app close at the launch after add firebase dynamics link flutter package on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I try to add dynamics link to my flutter app

I follow all steps from the package

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links

1. I create a Dynamic Links in firebase
2. I add capabilities to xcode
3. I create URL Type with my app bundle id
4. I add FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains to inflo.plist
5. I add package to pubspec.yaml and add example code to test

After this when I launch debug mode, the app crash direct after launch

Here is xcode log

```
Exception   NSException *   "`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/."    0x0000000283edf8a0
name    __NSCFConstantString *  "com.firebase.core" 0x0000000103378780
reason  __NSCFString *  "`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/."    0x0000000280b69fb0
userInfo    void *  NULL    0x0000000000000000
reserved    __NSDictionaryM *   2 key/value pairs   0x00000002830545c0



2021-02-17 11:01:35.108411+0100 Runner[15847:4634605] Metal API Validation Enabled
2021-02-17 11:01:35.583061+0100 Runner[15847:4634605] Configuring the default Firebase app...
2021-02-17 11:01:35.583239+0100 Runner[15847:4634720] 7.3.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
2021-02-17 11:01:35.583305+0100 Runner[15847:4634720] 7.3.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000004] App with name __FIRAPP_DEFAULT does not exist.
2021-02-17 11:01:35.585109+0100 Runner[15847:4634605] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: '`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x19c5b896c 0x19c2d1028 0x19c4a814c 0x103367518 0x102f2b8c4 0x102f2b69c 0x102f25fd4 0x102f266b4 0x102f26a10 0x1a06afc18 0x1a06b1a14 0x1a06b7340 0x19fe4fbec 0x1a0301518 0x19fe50724 0x19fe50154 0x19fe50540 0x19fe4fdc4 0x19fe54544 0x1a031b39c 0x1a022d7bc 0x1a031b354 0x19fe5425c 0x1a031b23c 0x19fe540b8 0x19fcbc434 0x19fcbaef8 0x19fcbc164 0x1a06b5730 0x1a024f6bc 0x1a17ade10 0x1a17d4aa0 0x1a17b8ef4 0x1a17d4734 0x1057a727c 0x1057aa9a4 0x1a17fb254 0x1a17faf00 0x1a17fb46c 0x19c534108 0x19c53405c 0x19c5337c8 0x19c52e694 0x19c52df40 0x1a67be534 0x1a06b9580 0x102f26c04 0x19c3ace18)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

thank you

Comment: add error logs please

Comment: Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           62,2s
Installing and launching...
and after the app close direct after launch no logs, it's lock to Installing and launching...

Comment: try to run your app using Xcode so it will give you proper error.

Comment: thank you, I add logs in the post

Comment: I've added answer please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Runner > `AppDelegate.swift`** file should be like below

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: It's work I just add GoogleService-Info.plist file to Xcode ^^ thank you for the help !!

Comment: Keep Growing! And approve and UP my answer if you like it. Thank you